# Argue by contradiction to show that there is no surjection...

Tags: elementary-set-theory

from $A$ to $\{0,1\}^A$. When $A$ is any (possibly infinite) set

How does one go about this?

Comment: Look up _Cantor's Theorem_ and the diagonal argument.

Comment: Do you mean $\{0,1\}^A$?

Comment: Umberto: yes, but in latex they dissapear

Comment: Tip: escape a curly bracket with a backslash, \{1,2,3\} generates $\{1,2,3\}$

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will check out cantors theorem.

Comment: There is almost surely a better duplicate. But this one will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** assume that $f: A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$ is a surjection. What can you say about B, where: $$A \supset B = \{a \in A: a \not \in f(a)\}$$